# How to convert floating into hex in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, ascii, non-ascii-characters

how to convert the floating variable into hex in JMETER.

Any idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) library in JMeter Distribution bundle which provides [Hex](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) class which in its turn exposes [encodeHex() function](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#encodeHex-byte:A-) which you can use to convert an ASCII string into its Hex representation like:

Given you need to convert `LLOP123344` string it's sufficient to call the aforementioned function like:

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString('LLOP123344'.getBytes('UTF-8'))
```

which returns `4c4c4f50313233333434`

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)